# Phpunit not recongnize log tag in phpuni.xml file

Tags: php, xml, phpunit

phpunit.xml version 8.2 does not recognize the log tag and gives me the following error:

Test results may not be as expected because the XML configuration file did not pass validation:

```
`Line 20:
Element 'log': This element is not expected.`
```

I checked the documentation, the tag is perfectly valid.

My phpunit.xml file:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    colors="true" 
    processIsolation="false" 
    stopOnFailure="false" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/10.1/phpunit.xsd" 
    cacheDirectory=".phpunit.cache">
  <coverage/>
  <php>
    <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>
    <ini name="apc.enable_cli" value="1"/>
  </php>
  <!-- Add any additional test suites you want to run here -->
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="app">
      <directory>./tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
  <logging>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="./report" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
    <log type="coverage-clover" target="./report/coverage.xml"/>
    <log type="coverage-php" target="./report/coverage.serialized"/>
    <log type="coverage-text" target="php://stdout" showUncoveredFiles="false"/>
    <log type="junit" target="./report/logfile.xml"/>
    <log type="testdox-html" target="./report/testdox.html"/>
    <log type="testdox-text" target="./report/testdox.txt"/>
  </logging>
  <source>
    <include>
      <directory suffix=".php">./src</directory>
    </include>
  </source>
</phpunit>`
```

I expect the code to work and create me the file with test coverage, but I can't get why is it uncorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is formatted for an old version of phpunit (seems like 6.x). In the xml header is the schema for 10.1 defined (`xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/10.1/phpunit.xsd"`). You may want to check the current [documentation](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.0/configuration.html#the-logging-element).

For xml errors it is recommended to check the schema. Validate it is the right one. There you may read the definition. A good xml parser helps with those errors.